# EmberJS simple ID from related object

Tags: ember.js

is there any way to do some filtering based on the related ID? imagine I have 2 models one is a song model and the other is an album model so obviously the song has album with an id, the json will return the model with

```
{album: 1}
```

so if I wanna filter it seems that I can't compare the album id with something like

```
song.get('album.id') === 1
```

is there any way to do it so simply?

Thanks

Edit: models

```
App.Album = DS.Model.extend({
   irrelevantstuff: DS.attr(),
   songs: DS.hasMany('Song')
})

App.Song = DS.Model.extend({
   irrelevantstuff: DS.attr(),
   album: DS.belongsTo('Album')
})
```

I tried both with `{async:true}` and without, still same problem.

however I noticed that if I run it the first time it gives me undefined to all of the album.id but if I run it the second time I get the ids, now I have everything on the store, so it's not doing an AJAX request either the first or second time.

```
{"songs": [{"irrelevantstuff":"foo", "album": 1}, {"irrelevantstuff":"bar", "album": 1}]}

{"albums": [{"irrelevantstuff":"album", "songs": [1,2]}]
```

Comment: Are you using a client side record management framework, such as Ember Data or Ember Model?  If so, what do the model definitions look like.  If not, are you using POJOs?

Comment: @kingpin2k I added the way the model relates to each other, and I'm using emberdata, the problem is the first time it seems to not have the info but it does the second time around it seems

Comment: will you show the json that's returned on your request for a song/album

Comment: @kingpin2k ok I added the json, there's obviously more fields but they don't really matter, that's what I get back from the json, and I get back everything at once, and keep everything on the store

Comment: so song/album are async then.

Comment: yes they are I suppose, but it shouldn't matter I mean the id is right there it's stupid that ember would just hide that information, it's literally right there!!

Comment: Ember/Ember Data are two different products, Ember doesn't require Ember Data at all, you can use POJOs just fine in it.  And Technically it isn't right there, when you using Ember Data you are creating records and morphing your json into more complex objects.  So accessing song.get('album') really triggers Ember Data to fetch the album data, since it assumes you want to use the data now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Relationships should be camelCase

```
App.Album = DS.Model.extend({
   irrelevantstuff: DS.attr(),
   songs: DS.hasMany('song', {async: true})
})

App.Song = DS.Model.extend({
   irrelevantstuff: DS.attr(),
   album: DS.belongsTo('album', {async: true})
})
```

Since your data for the relationship isn't coming down in the request for the song/album it would be considered async.  As such if you want to access it you'll need to use it asynchronous methods, promises.

```
var songPromise = this.store.find('song', 1);

songPromise.then(function(song){
  var albumPromise = song.get('album');
  albumPromise.then(function(album){
    // the album is available for usage....
    if(album.get('id') == 1){
      alert('woo hoo');
    }
  });
});
```